# bash script led keyboard in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, keyboard, led

I use this simple bash script in order to power on my keyboard led in my linux VM .
If i don't use the script i can't power on led.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
xset led 3
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

When i tried to launch it works , but if i insert in crontab doesn't.

```
@reboot /home/giacomo/Desktop/keyboard.sh
```

can you help me ?

i even tried to put in crontab the commands , doesn't work.

I tried insert it in root crontab, doesn't work.

```
@reboot xset led 3 ;  xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

i want  to automatically power on led of keyboard at reboot, without launch it myself.

thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info for a lot of pointers on problems with crontabs. This sort of Q gets asked every month, so also spend some time searching here. Good luck.

Comment: Multiple notes here: (1) Tools starting with `x` are related to the X11 abandonware; they may not do much in the Wayland era… (2) If a legacy X.org server is indeed used, it is likely that the user running `cron` cannot talk to it; it’s not the the logged-in user, the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variables may be missing etc. (3) Always **avoid `cron`**; it is a flawed and outdated piece of technology. Use `systemd`’s `.trimer` units instead. They bring flexibility, reliability, statefulness, log management, dependency tracking and much more. This problem would be easy to debug with `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

Confused on your choice of approach for what you are trying to do.

Why are you **not** putting that code snippet in your **~/.bashrc-local**, which will be left untouched by OS updates that modify **~/.bashrc** ?